# Simple Paypal button integration results in 404 error

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have business and personal account set up, subscriptions, plans... all setup for simple paypal button POC in sandbox.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxx&vault=true&intent=subscription"></script>
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
    <script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.subscription.create({
            'plan_id': 'P-66899082RN487441DMXZKF7I'
        });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            console.log(data, '\n', actions);
            alert('You have successfully subscribed to ' + data.subscriptionID);
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

(I've replaced the client id with xxxx, but in reality I've put valid client id instead)

However, I got 404 in the first place, when paypal plugin starts pinging its own endpoint:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions
404 error

following the bunch of errors in the console:

rest_api_v1_billing_subscriptions_create_error ,
create_order_error ,
Uncaught Error: Create Subscription Api response error
...etc.

I used the exact form form the official integration manual:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/

[image: Dashboard with subscription plans]

[image: Console errors]

Comment: paypal's sdk script is declared inside <body> in the example you linked, while in your pasted code it is declared inside <head>. Could it be that?

Comment: I'm afraid it is not. I just updated it, retried, same errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is `P-66899082RN487441DMXZKF7I` from? We can only guess it was ***not*** generated with the client-id the JS SDK is being loaded with, hence the 404 error.

The simplest way to obtain a working identifier and client-id for sandbox mode is from the sandbox account interface at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/plans . Otherwise, you need to create a product and plan with the [corresponding API calls](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#link-createproduct), information (request+response) of which is not in your question. The "following the bunch of errors in the console" information is also incomplete.

Comment: It's from the dashboard sandbox.paypal.com. Colleagues from BE configured it and they already use it for recurring payments etc. So I picked one of their subscription plans. I added the capture in original post

Comment: The link you provided https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#link-createproduct , they did all that (items 1 and 2) and I jumped in to integrate item 3

Comment: As for "following the bunch of errors in the console" I provided 3 errors. I could capture console full of red text full of hashes if you wish, but I don't see the point, it would take me at least 2 captures

Comment: I uploaded errors from console, BTW.
My guess would be that it could be CORS error, but: 1) Why doesn't it display cors error? 2) I tried localhost and also deployed it on a test site, both has same result

Comment: This has nothing to do with CORS, I don't know why you would think so. The error clearly tells you the request _did_ reach the server, but the server returned "resource not found". Instead, I came to the same conclusion as Preston PHX. The client ID you use seems to belong to a different account than the one you are logged into with your browser. So the plan you or your colleagues created in the other account in the browser can't be found by the API as it doesn't exist in the account the client ID belongs to. Make sure to follow the steps in the link above to get the correct client ID!

Comment: I assure you it is the same client ID! We don't have any other client ID! I posted you a dashboard of that same client ID, containing that particular plan.

Comment: Seems that colleague gave me the wrong client ID after all. I apoligize to all of you